# r change column type of columns names with pattern

Tags: r, string, dataformat, column-types

If my dataset has columns like this

```
ID   Group  Col_item_01   Col_item_02   Col_item 03  
1    Blue    11.23        10.12         4.3
2    Green   10.21        18.24         5.9
4    Purple  4.23          7.64         15.97
```

How can I convert all the columns starting with , `Col_item_...` to type numeric from character ? I know I can do this individually ,  `df1$Col_item_01 <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Col_item_01)` but I am interested in an efficient approach using grep or grepl or string functions to extract just these columns starting with `Col_item_...` and changing them to numeric. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may loop `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'Col_item_' and convert to `numeric` in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
       mutate(across(starts_with("Col_item_"),
              ~ as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

---

Or in `base R`, get the column names with pattern using `grep` and loop over the selected columns in `lapply` and do the assignment

```
nm1 <- grep("^Col_item_", names(df1))
df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[nm1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: I made some changes to capture only columns ending with numbers on the backend and it worked perfect. Thanks ...again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `type.convert`:

```
df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)
```